# how to use a relative date but static time

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that runs at 11 o'clock every day. i have a second report that is designed to run two days later. the second report needs to catch all of the records that were input after the first report was run. so the second report has criteria similar to the following

```
... where {TABLE.INSERT_DATE}>{@CURRENT_DATETIME_LESS_TWO})...
```

where current_datetime_less two is a formula that subtracts 2 from crystals CurrentDateTime function

how do i specify that the value in the insert_date column should be

```
(currentdate -2 at 11 o'clock)
```

or

```
(currentdatetime -2 at 11 0'clock)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datetime(date(currentdatetime-2),time(10,0,0))
```